# Download Images from CSV column to Django ImageField

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-rest-framework

Since I am using ImageField model in django, i need to save these images to the database, as well as the respective title and description.

response.content returns a binary blob of the image and the ImageField expects a valid image, I am just hitting a roadblock here.

This is my sample csv data

```
title   description     image
Item 1  Description 1   http://www.imgur.com/784/77987987.jpg
Item 2  Description 2   http://www.image.com/images/797-oijio.jpg
Item 3  Description 3   https://www.google.com/logo.jpg
```

this is my image model,

```
class Image(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'images'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title




import csv
import validators
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import requests
from images.models import Image

def get_image_content(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.content

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('filepath'),

    def handle(self, **options):
        csv_path = options["filepath"]
        with open(csv_path) as f:
            data = list(csv.DictReader(f))

        images = []
        for row in data:
            if validators.url(row['image']):
                img, _ = Image.objects.get_or_create(title=row['title'])
                img.description = row['description']
                # download image, populate filename and img_raw_data variables
                img.image.save(filename, img_raw_data, save=True)
                img.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
import urllib
from urlparse import urlparse
from django.core.files import File

#code
result = urllib.urlretrieve(row['image'])
filename = urlparse(row['image']).path.split('/')[-1]

img.image.save(
        filename,
        File(open(result[0]))
        )
img.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected. Is there anyway we can do in in a much optimized manner ?

Comment: This is one of the recommended usage. If you are considering speed, you need parallel programming like `threads`

Comment: I have another question, Is urllib.urlretrieve(row['image']) like similar functionality available via requests ?

Comment: I had done this `def get_image_content(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.content` but it returns me a binary blob right ?